# How to create a simple formik field for entering date and time?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to create a very simple formik field for entering date and time. The requirements are:

1. The field's value should be a JavaScript `Date`.
2. The field should allow entering free-form text in an input field and convert it to a `Date` on blur events.
3. The field should display an error if the entered string cannot be converted to a valid date.
4. If the form is reset, the field should show the initial value of the date.

While I was able to satisfy requirements 1 & 2 quite easily, I am having trouble with requirements 3 & 4. I think part of the problem is that I am storing the raw text of the input field in internal state. However, I can't think of another way. Is there a better pattern?

Here's my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-datetime-field-f3cn4?file=/src/DateTimeField.tsx). Please see the sections marked with "Issue 1" & "Issue 2"

Comment: Why not to use built-in Field and pass your custom control to it:  `<Field name="date" placeholder="Jan 1, 2019 9:00 AM" component={DateTimeField}/>` ?

Comment: Hmmm, haven't tried Field but conceptually it looks like it will do some auto-wiring which I am doing manually. Is there anything about <Field> that will overcome my issues?

Comment: Just checkout docs https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field . It should overcome your reset issue at least.

Comment: Hi @Rostyslav, I tried <Field> but it makes no difference. Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-datetime-field-v3-juycw?file=/src/App.tsx. As far as I can tell from the docs, <Field> is simply a component equivalent of the useField() hook which I was already using. I still think that the basic issue is supporting a Date type, which is forcing a conversion to string, which I must keep in local state. I have not seen any example similar to this.

Comment: I have combined my thoughts in the answer. Please, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

1. Use `Field` component from Formik to bind your custom component

```
<Field name="date" timezone={DefaultTz} component={DateTimeField} />
```

2. Use `form` property from `Field` to display errors

```
{form.errors.date ? (
  <div className="text-danger">{form.errors.date}</div>
) : null}
```

3. Use spread operator to bind formik fields and your custom blur which converts the date

```
<input
  className="form-control"
  placeholder={format}
  {...{ ...field, onBlur }}
/>
```

Altogether it looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import { DateUtils } from "@react-force/date-utils";

export interface DateTimeFieldProps extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<Date> {
  field: any;
  form: any;
  timezone: string;
  format?: string;
}

export const DateTimeField = ({
  field,
  form,
  timezone,
  format = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A",
}: DateTimeFieldProps) => {
  const onBlur = () => {
    try {
      form.setValues({
        date: DateUtils.createDate(field.value, format, timezone),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={format}
        {...{ ...field, onBlur }}
      />
      {form.errors.date ? (
        <div className="text-danger">{form.errors.date}</div>
      ) : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

The working version is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-datetime-field-m0ml5?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks @Rostyslav, this looks very good! The remaining issue is that a valid date is displayed as "Tue Jan 01 2019 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)". It should honor the specified format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A". Please see my updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-datetime-field-v3-juycw. Have I missed something?

Comment: In order to display the Date object <Input> converts Date by default to string using its `.toString()` method. If you want the specific format you have to work in strings and not on Date objects.

Comment: Thanks again, Rostyslav. This is exactly what I was afraid of. In the past, I have always been transforming complex data types (like date) into simpler ones (like string), but that involves annoying translations at the form level. I wanted to see if I can make these transformations go away - hence this attempt. Before I give up, I have asked @jaredpalmer if he has any recommendations. Please see https://spectrum.chat/palmer/general/how-to-create-a-simple-formik-field-for-entering-date-and-time~be9e591e-d263-4db7-9846-84d326169c80

Comment: @Naresh you see Date objects depend on the implementation of JS engine (behave differently in various browsers). Therefore, I would personally go with strings as they are consistent and if I would need some operations which are available to Date only I would extract this processing to some separate helper functions. Anyways, I am really curious of jaredpalmer answer

Comment: You are correct - Date objects are implementation dependent, so I don't want to rely on them. However, I am relying on the momentjs library, which provides a very predictable way for parsing and formatting dates. If you dig into my DateUtils functions, they are all leveraging momentjs.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that there is no JSON type for date. You cannot pass momentjs object or Date object over HTTP. You would still have to convert it to string @Naresh

Comment: Again you are correct. Date is my internal representation for a date. When I send it to the server over HTTP, it is serialized to the ISO8601 format.

Comment: No response from @jaredpalmer so far. I am switching over to strings. Thanks for all your help Rostyslav.